# microservices' async communication for business transaction

Tags: rest, events, design-patterns, architecture, microservices

## Problem

Inside a microservice architecture, consider a `service A` which receives a request from an user and persist some data in to its database.

Once persisted, `service A` has to notify `service B`. This notification action to `service B` can happen asynchronously(not needed immediately).

## Design

A few ways to implement the above requirement could be:

### Approach #1

1. `service A` persist(insert + commit) data in to DB
2. pushes a message into a queue for `service B` to consume
3. return success to the user

### Approach #2

1. `service A` persist(insert + commit) data in to DB
2. transaction outbox pattern with CDC and KAFKA
3. `service B` is a subscriber to a topic in KAFKA and fetches the message

## Questions

1. Option 1 is very simple as compared to option 2. But, it introduces dual write problem. In my previous organization(a mid size start-up), we followed option 1(used aws sqs) widely without any issue. Was it because 99.9% availability SLA given by aws and were lucky to have never faced any major issue? Is dual write problem really that big to worry about?
2. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a microservice architecture like the one you're describing, the primary goal is to ensure that Service A can reliably and efficiently notify Service B once it has persisted data. Let's break down the two approaches you've mentioned and then discuss the dual-write problem and additional alternatives.

**Approach #1: Queue System**

- Service A persists data in its database (insert + commit).
- Service A pushes a message into a queue (like AWS SQS) for Service B
  to consume.
- Service A returns success to the user.

**Pros:**

- It's straightforward to implement.
- Service A doesn't need to know about the internals of Service B.
- The queue can handle high loads and smooth out traffic spikes.

**Cons:**

- If Service A successfully writes to the database but fails to send
  the message to the queue (or if the message gets lost in the queue),
  Service B won't be notified.
- Ensuring the data is in sync between the two services can be
  challenging.

**Approach #2: Transaction Outbox with CDC and Kafka**

- Service A persists data in its database (insert + commit).
- Transaction outbox pattern is used, where an "outbox" table in the
  database is updated as part of the same transaction.
- Change Data Capture (CDC) picks up changes in the outbox table and
  pushes them to Kafka.
- Service B subscribes to a Kafka topic and fetches the message when
  it    appears.

Pros:

- The dual-write problem is mitigated as both database write and
  message notification are part of the same transaction.
- Scalability and Performance: Kafka can handle high throughput and
  provides additional features like replaying messages or scaling
  consumers.

Cons:

- Requires setting up and managing Kafka and CDC, which can be complex
  and might introduce new failure modes.
- More moving parts mean more monitoring, tuning, and maintenance.

The dual write problem is significant because it affects data consistency and system reliability. If one write succeeds (to the database) but the other fails (to the queue or outbox), the systems can become out of sync. The severity depends on how critical it is for Service B to receive all notifications without loss or delay. In systems where consistency isn't as critical, or where occasional manual intervention is acceptable, the dual-write problem might be less of a concern.

**Additional Approaches**

1. **Event Sourcing:** Instead of writing directly to the database, Service A writes events to a log. The database and other services
   become subscribers to this log, ensuring all state changes are
   captured as events and can be reacted upon by multiple services.
2. **Database Triggers:** Use database triggers to automatically send notifications or write to a queue/table when certain conditions are
   met. This can ensure atomicity between data persistence and
   notification.
3. **Direct HTTP Call:** Service A could make a direct HTTP call to Service B post-persistence. This can be made more reliable with
   retries, circuit breakers, and ensuring idempotency, but it doesn't
   offer as much decoupling as other methods.

Approach #1 might be sufficient for systems where eventual consistency is acceptable or where the volume and criticality of the messages don't justify the added complexity of Approach #2. However, for systems requiring strong consistency and reliability, investing in more robust solutions like Approach #2 or exploring additional approaches might be necessary. Consider the trade-offs in terms of development and operational complexity, performance, and reliability to choose the right approach for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

### Messaging system related failure models for your situtation

1. Database transaction committed but message queue is temporarily unavailable
2. Database transaction committed but message broker nack the message
3. Database transaction committed but message broker did not respond in time

### Approach #1

If you have a transient network issue between your application and the messaging system then a retry mechanism could be helpful here depending on the requirements. BUT during the failed retry attempts you have to store somewhere the undelivered messages. If you use a node-local non-persistent queue then your application is vulnerable for message loss in case of application crash or node restart. If you have a node-local persistent queue for your to-be-retried messages then your application and its monitoring becomes more complex.

If the message broker returns a negative acknowledgement (nack) then depending on many factors you might want to retry that message / put it on a dead letter queue (DLQ) / discard it / ...

If your application did not receive any acknowledgement from the broker within a given time frame then you can suspect that you have a transient network issue.

## Approach #2

If your CDC process can not reach temporarily the messaging system then it will simply retry later. It doesn't have to worry about the to-be-retried messages' durability since they are committed into a database as part of the outbox pattern. Some sophisticated CDC processes can be configured with `maxRetry` configuration to do not retry indefinitely.

The other two failure models are handled in the same way as in case of approach #1.

---

Please bear in mind that in case of approach #2 the CDC process might do the message migration not continuously just periodically. That means there is an added delay due to time or message quantity based buffering.

Comment: Thank you @Peter for your explanation. From practical point of view for an early to mid size startup, do I have to worry about the above mentioned cases? Reason: solving them just keeps on adding new components and complexity in the system. I just want to understand how companies are dealing with such scenarios?

Comment: @ratatouille IMHO not the company size should drive the decision which solution to pick. Rather than the business requirements. Since your question is not listing them it is hard (if not impossible) to provide any guidance on which one to pick.